# How i resize UITableView in my code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to landscape when the image does not appear. To do this I'm trying to resize the table to get over the image but it is not working.

image app landscape:
[IMAGE](http://postimg.org/image/skw0246qd/)

my code:

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) {
        self.imageMenu.hidden = false;
    } else {
        self.imageMenu.hidden = true;
        CGRect temp = self.tbMenu.frame;
        temp.origin.y = 38;
        temp.origin.x = 0;
    }
}
```

Could you help me!

Comment: Means when image not available you want your view controller in landscape mode?

Comment: when in landscape mode the table has to be on top and the image becomes Hidden = true. But when it invisible even the space where it is still and will not pro table top

Comment: But in code you have not written code of setting tableviews frame for portrait mode. and Hide/Show imageView according to that.

Comment: I've tried so many things and blacked out, I will make an update of the code, could help me?

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: I believe I'm using yes

Comment: Than you can't set frame you need to change constrains for that. Create object of top space constrains and change it according to device mode.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: Your table contains top space constrains?

Comment: Now i remove all constrains!